# Is this a valid proof for ${x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}}}} = y$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, tetration

So I got this challenge from my teacher.

**Solve ${x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}}}} = y$ (eq. 1) for $x$.**

---

My attempt:

As $x^{y^z}$ per definition equals $x^{y \cdot z}$, then $x^y = y$ from (eq. 1). Thus, **$x = \sqrt{y}$.**

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: $x^{y^z}$ is **not** by definition equal to $x^{y\cdot z}$. The correct equation is $(x^y)^z = x^{y\cdot z}$ and $x^{y^z}$ is actually $x^{(y^z)}$ and is not connected to the previous equation.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317314/derivative-of-xxx-to-infinity/1317337#1317337) (it does not tackle exactly the same question, but in particular there is your answer there).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a correct proof, no.

If $${x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}}}} = y$$ then we can say that $x$ to the power of each side is the same:

$$x^{\left({x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}}}}\right)} = x^y$$

but then the left hand side is what exactly what we started with (provided the limit exists) so we can equate the right hand sides of each of these equations:

$$y=x^y\implies x=y^{1/y}$$

Answer (score 7):

Really? $x^{y^z}$ equals $x^{y\cdot z}$? So you are saying that $$2=2^1=2^{1^2} = 2^{1\cdot 2} = 2^2 = 4?$$

Comment: Is $2^{1^2}  = 2^{(1^2)}$ or $(2^1)^2$?

Comment: @WarrenHill Well, the OP wrote $x^{y^z}$ which is short for $x^{(y^z)}$.

Comment: It is only short for that if you use that convention.  Mathematicians do use that convention.  But (most) calculators associate left-to-right, so use the OP's convention.

Comment: @GEdgar I would argue that this is standard notation and that OP misunderstood his convention.

Comment: Take any calculator, do [2] [$x^y$] [3] [$x^y$] [4] and see what you get.

Comment: @GEdgar I don't care what I get. The fact is that OP almost certainly misunderstood the convention. The accepted answer also assumes that.

Answer (score 2):

Once you prove that over the interval $\left[e^{-e},e^{\frac{1}{e}}\right]$:
$$ f(x)=x^{x^{x^{x^{\ldots}}}} = \frac{W(-\log x)}{-\log x}\tag{1}$$
where $W$ is the [Lambert W-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), it follows that:
$$ f^{-1}(x) = x^{\frac{1}{x}}.\tag{2} $$
On the other hand,
$$ x = x^{f(x)} \tag{3} $$
implies:
$$ x = f^{-1}(x)^x \tag{4}$$
hence $(2)$ is quite trivial.