# Powers of powers. Is there a single interpretation of this notation

Tags: notation

Prompted by [another question on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1318481/86986) is this notation clear and unambiguous

$$x^{y^z}$$

One answer there seems to imply the meaning is 
$$x^{(y^z)}$$

Mathcad seams to agree with this making $2^{3^2} = 2^9 = 512$

On the other hand my Casio calculator iterprets this as

$$(x^y)^z$$

Making $2^{3^2} = (2^3)^2 = 8^2 = 64$

My simple question is either of these interpretations correct or do I need to put the brackets in to clarify as I always would anyway.

Comment: the first one is the only correct interpretation.

Comment: The Casio interpretation violates the usual convention.

Comment: You are probably typing it wrongly into the Casio calculator as it would appear to you being correct. This is similar to typing $-1^2$ and getting $-1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is used in mathematics, because $(x^y)^z$ is more simply written $x^{yz}$. The same goes for at least some programming languages (Haskell comes to mind), for the same reason.