# Differentiation of infinite power ladder

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

Consider the function, $$f(x)=x^{x^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.{^.}}}}}}}$$While differentiating it with respect to $x$ (provided that $f(x)$ evaluates to a finite value), we were made to write $f(x)=x^{f(x)}$.

> **My question is:** Why we can't write it as $f(x)=(f(x))^x$ and then differentiate implicitly? Both the ways of writing mean the same thing.

Comment: If you write $f(x) = (f(x))^x$, consider $f(x) = 1$ a constant function. It satisfies the property as well.

Comment: Possibly related: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317314/derivative-of-xxx-to-infinity) alongside its linked posts.

Comment: because you power is repeating in $x$ that is why  you take $f(x)=x^{f((x)}$

Answer (score 3):

You have to be a bit careful here. The point is that, for each $x$, $f(x)$ is defined as $f(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty} p_n(x)$, where $p_n$ means applying $n$ times "$x$ to the power", e.g, $p_2(x) = x^{x^x}$. (Note that is is not the same as $(x^x)^x$!) Then it follows that

$$ f(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty} p_n(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty} p_{n+1}(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty} x^{p_{n}(x)} =  x^{\lim_{n\to \infty} p_{n}(x)} = x^{f(x)}. $$

We cannot do a similar sequence of equalities to arrive at your expression $f(x) = f(x)^x$.

Comment: Many thanks. I wanted to know will the ordered pair $(x,f(x))$ satisfy the equality $f(x)={f(x)}^x$ and if it satisfies it then this form ought to be  correct.

Comment: @VanshSaini Fixing $f(x)=y$, the only solution to $y = y^x$ is $x=1$ unless $y=1$ or $y=0$. Hence the only function $f$ defined on an open subset of $\mathbb R$ satisfying $f(x)=f(x)^x$ is the function $f(x)=1$.

Comment: Got it..................